# gmock: force mocking out of a class method without defining and referencing a mock class?

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

the normal pattern of gmock testing is

```cpp
    class MyMockClass : public MyRealClass {
        /// swap out behavior of an existng method
        MOCK_method(some_method .....);
    
    }
    
    TEST() {
    
    
        MyMockClass mock;
        EXPECT_CALLED(mock.some_method);
    
        /// ******* here I have to explicitly pass in the mock obj into the system
        MyConsumerClass myconsumer(mock);
        myconsumer.do_something_to_trigger_mock__some_method();
    }
```

in the above "****" line I have to explicitly pass in a mock obj into the system, i.e. compose my consumer obj with a mock obj. But now I face an existing consumer class impl, its constructor does not allow passing in the dependency objects; in fact I can probably argue that it's impossible to list all the dependency objects in the ctor of a consumer class; more importantly, my real case is that the consumer class to be tested sits several levels above the mock obj:

```cpp
    class MyConsumerClass {
    
       private:
          MyHelperClass helper
    
       public:
           void trigger() {
              helper.trigger_again();
           }
    }
    
    class MyHelperClass {
    
        BottomClass bottom;
        public:
           void trigger_again() {
               bottom.do_something();
        }
    }
    
    class BottomClass {
    
        public :
        void do_something();
    }
```

in this case, in our unit test, we can only instantiate the top level MyConsumerClass, and I was hoping to verify that when I call myconsumer.trigger(), I could verify that the BottomClass.do_something() is called, possibly also verifying that it's called with a specific argument. But the above class hierarchy is written so that I can not pass in a mock BottomClass obj from the top level.

in jmock or jmockit, I remember it's possible to globally wipe out the behavior of BottomClass.do_something(), without referring to a specific mock obj, i.e. "static mocking", as they are called in jmockit. is it possible to do something like that in gmock (c++)? thanks

Comment: I can think of two things: 1. Why don't you test your classes separately? For example, write a separate test for `MyHelperClass`. 2. If dependency injection doesn't work for you, GMock allows you to do static mocking by templatizing your classes: Convert your classes to templates, then instantiate the template with real classes for production and with mock classes for testing. See here for an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxCH4AuVRgo&t=4036s

Answer (score 0):

Converting the comment to an answer:

I can think of two things:

1. Why don't you test your classes separately? For example, write a separate test for MyHelperClass.
2. If dependency injection doesn't work for you, GMock allows you to do static mocking by templatizing your classes: Convert your classes to templates, then instantiate the template with real classes for production and with mock classes for testing. See here for an example.

In your case, your code could be rewritten to something like this:

```cpp
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Real classes used in production
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class BottomClass {
 public:
  void do_something();
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Templatized classes used in test or production
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class BType>
class MyHelperClass {
 public:
  BType bottom;

 public:
  void trigger_again() { bottom.do_something(); }
};

template <class BType, template <typename> class HType>
class MyConsumerClass {
 public:
  HType<BType> helper;

 public:
  void trigger() { helper.trigger_again(); }
};
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Mocked classes used in test
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class MockedBottomClass {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(void, do_something, (), ());
};

TEST(BottomClassTest, Test1) {
  MyConsumerClass<MockedBottomClass, MyHelperClass> mock;
  EXPECT_CALL(mock.helper.bottom, do_something());

  mock.trigger();
}
```

I had to convert some of your private members to public members for the test to work.

Live example here: https://godbolt.org/z/qc3chdxKz